# Tor customize connection path and speed

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection

I need your help for 2 questions that I'm struggling with.

1. How does the path of nodes matters to the connections speed? E.g will my connections speed be faster if the tor connection goes: Germany->China->Argentina->France instead of Germany->Denmark->Italy->France. I suppose the answer to this is yes but please elaborate if there are any specific details that a newcomer might miss.
2. If the answer to the first question is yes, is there a way to tweak the path that my connection will take. E.g If I'm in Germany and want to access a French website, can I somehow tell tor to use only European nodes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could harm your anonymity to reduce the possible circuit paths. It's possible to do it but there's little guarantee that it would improve circuit bandwidth, infact you might exclude faster nodes. Tor already picks node weighted on their bandwidth (along with a few other factors).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to reduce the number of path, I just want to confine it in certain geo region. You said that it can be done, do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction option available based on region's.
but you can specify the exact countries for the region you prefer, only for guards and exits. according to [https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en](http://tor%20command%20line%20options)

torrc example:

> StrictNodes 1
>   EntryNodes US,CA,RU
>   ExitNodes US,CA,RU

If you are familiar with python and want more (e.x: restriction upon middle nodes as well) you can use stem api here: [https://stem.torproject.org/](http://stem%20library)
for your case below link gives you good hints of custom path selection (control over guards,middles and exit nodes) [https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html](http://custom%20path%20selection)

good luck.